# How can you query all objects for fields with the same name?

Tags: apex, soql

For example, search all objects to find those that have a field named "Phone__c", and then query those fields.

The intent is to then update the "Phone__c" field on all the records that exist in those objects.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the end goal here? If you're trying to search for generalized contact information, a full-text SOSL search may be a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate each object and its fields to find those which have a specific API Name as below. I recommend you perform any queries separately, one per transaction.

```
public static List<SObjectType> getObjectsWithField(String apiName)
{
    List<SObjectType> sObjectTypes = new List<SObjectType>();
    for (SObjectType sObjectType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values())
    {
        if (sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey(apiName))
        {
            sObjectTypes.add(sObjectType);
        }
    }
    return sObjectTypes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to then update the field 'apiName' on all the records that exist on the objects in sObjectTypes?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT Id,TableEnumOrId, DeveloperName  FROM CustomField WHERE DeveloperName = 'Phone'

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this answer is what we call a _code dump_. Code dumps tend not to be great answers because they don't help the person asking the question understand what their problem was, or how to avoid similar issues in the future. They also tend to generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" which makes it hard for other people with similar problems to follow. This answer would be improved if you were to put more effort into describing how you arrived at this query.

Comment: e.g. pointing out that custom fields are stored in an SObject, showing documentation that tells us that this information can be queried, and explaining what pieces of information in the result of the query are important.